# Android webview with video is showing half size of the window

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to use flash player to stream video from a server.

In some cases (not always) it looks like the webview is defined to be half size of the screen.

I already defined my activity to be full screened.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you use the emulator ?

Comment: no, I'm using Samsung (s2)....

Answer (score 0):

I did it earlier with two webviews. I did it by using `android:layout_weight` to 1 for both the web views and it filled up the screen.

If you want just one web view, use another linear layout for the remaining items, and set `android:layout_weight="1"` to both the webview and the linear layout.

Comment: I already did that... the problem is that sometimes it's fine and some times it's not...